# How to test a histogram against a specific distribution?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, histogram

## Prerequisites

If I have **given**

- a histogram $y_1, \ldots, y_m$,
- as a hypothesis for the underlying distribution some discrete iid random variables $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ supported in $\mathbb Z$
- where the $y_1, \ldots, y_m$ are realisations of $Y_1, \ldots, Y_m$ respectively with

$$
Y_k := \sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{kX_i} \quad, k=1,\ldots, m.
$$

Here $\delta_{kX_i}$ denotes the [Kronecker delta](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta).

Now, I am **looking** for a statistical test for the goodness of fit for the hypothesized distribution. All parameters for the distributions $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ are known a priori.

## Question

What is the general approach to such a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely too long for a comment and suggests some potential answers, but I hope to expand on it once you address the issues.

...

> a histogram $y_1,…,y_m$

Are the categories always on a lattice, and these are actually observations from a discrete distribution on a lattice (so we have ordering and equispacing)?

> I am looking for a statistical test which tells me whether the hypothesis is true.

No test will tell you whether a distributional hypothesis is true.

There are a variety of possible tests for the goodness of fit of a hypothesized distribution.

Is there any parameter estimation involved here?

> I am not looking for a parameter test.

Do you mean a parametric test?

> What is the solution for the hypothesis X1,…,Xn∼Geo(p)?

Is $p$ known? What do the first few $Y$'s look like here?

---

A commonly used approach would be to perform a chi-square for this kind of goodness of fit, but this is usually not a good idea because it ignores the ordering (losing power to uninteresting alternatives). If I've understood everything correctly, I'd suggest *either* an Anderson-Darling (but modified to allow for the discreteness - which will probably require simulation of the null distribution), or a Smooth Test (see the discussion and links [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/60906/805)).

For tests *other* than Smooth Tests, see:

D'Agostino, R. B. and Stephens, M. A. (1986).
*Goodness-of-Fit Techniques.*
New York: Marcel Dekker.

If you have parameter estimation, things become more complex, but can be dealt with.

---

In respect of your previously mentioned Geometric distribution example, a smooth test for the geometric is covered in

Best, D.J. and Rayner, J.C.W. (2003).
"Tests of fit for the geometric distribution."
*Communications in Statistics - Simulation and Computation*,
32 (4), 1065-1078.

It's also in Section 8.4 of

Rayner J. C. W., O. Thas, D. J. Best. (2009),
*Smooth Tests of Goodness of Fit: Using R*, 2nd Edition.
ISBN: 978-0-470-82442-9
http://biomath.ugent.be/~othas/smooth2/Home.html

R packages that do smooth tests include [ddst](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ddst/ddst.pdf) and [smoothtest](http://biomath.ugent.be/~othas/smooth2/R-Package.html). The package ddst doesn't do the geometric case (though it does do the exponential distribution). I haven't checked what smoothtest contains, but since it does with the book linked just above, I expect it may implement the geometric one there. I don't know whether smoothtest runs under the most recent version of R, (but older versions of R can be set up).

Comment: I've edited the question and hope this clarifies your questions.

Comment: If anything, your edit made it less clear, not more. You no longer really seem to discuss the distribution at all, and you removed the only part that gave me any real clue what you were doing. Now I'm even less certain I understand what you're asking. Are $Y_i$'s count random variables? Is the distribution of $\bf{Y}$ essentially multinomial,  specifically a [mixture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution) of $X$-distributions? I am no longer confident that this is what you mean. There remain several other questions or requests outstanding that would help.

Comment: The $Y_k$s are random variables which simple count the number of $X_i$s that result in the value $k$. Example: Throw an ordinary dice $100$ times: $X_1, \ldots, X_{100} \sim Uniform(\{1, \ldots, 6\})$. Then $Y_k$, $k = 1, \ldots, 6$ counts the number of times a $k$ was thrown. A histogram then could look like $y = (13, 11, 13, 15, 24, 24)$.

Comment: Thanks; I have edited to reflect your clarification and added some information. There are a number of outstanding questions there. One of them in particular - is the distribution of $X$ completely specified, or in general are there estimated parameters?